# How to register GTM Google Analytics event links to anchors(#)?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to register Events in Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager, but I can't get it to register.

This is what I have setup:

**Tag**

> Track type: Event
>
> Google Analytics Settings: {{GoogleAnalyticsID}}

**Trigger**

> Clicks-Just Links (Wait for Tags 2000)
>
> Page URL contains '/'
>
> Click link contains '#something'

Comment: Did you make sure that  "check validation" is unchecked? GTM does not consider fragment identifiers valid links. Also you might want to uncheck the "wait for tags" thing, it often creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: Check validation is unchecked. I also tried without the 'Wait for Tags' and there was no difference.